# Java: JFrame icon not showing in titlebar (OS X)

Tags: macos, icons, jframe

I am trying to add an icon to a JFrame titlebar in OS X. The code I have used is:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/images/theIcon.gif");
System.out.println("Icon dimensions are " + icon.getIconWidth() + " by " + icon.getIconHeight());
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

No icon shows up, and the console output shows the correct dimensions for the image.
There must be something wrong with the expression `setIconImage(icon.getImage())`, but I can't see what.

I am on Mac OS 10.8.2, running Java SE 6 and Eclipse Juno. Actually, I'm wondering if this is an OS X issue.

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not paint the title bar with an icon by default. You can enable the cross platform look and feel to paint the icon. However, doing that might hurt your eyes, as it is not particularly pretty.

Do this before creating the JFrame (e.g. in the `main` method).

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's a screenshot with and without the above code:

[image: JFrame with and without cross platform l&f]